# Spawn issue with mpi4py in the Anaconda Python distribution

Tags: mpi, anaconda, mpi4py

`mpi4py.MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn` seems to throw errors when using Anaconda's Python distribution. My question is whether it is possible that `mpi4py` is built against the wrong version of MPI (mpich v openmpi) in my installation of Anaconda in some way.

The issue is that the following code

```
# spawn.py
import mpi4py.MPI as MPI
import sys
print 'mpi4py:',MPI.__file__
comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable,
                           args=['hello.py'],
                           maxprocs=1)
```

gives the following error

```
$ /home/wd15/anaconda/bin/python spawn.py
mpi4py: /home/wd15/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpi4py/MPI.so
[mpiexec@loki] match_arg (./utils/args/args.c:122): unrecognized argument pmi_args
[mpiexec@loki] HYDU_parse_array (./utils/args/args.c:140): argument matching returned error
[mpiexec@loki] parse_args (./ui/mpich/utils.c:1387): error parsing input array
[mpiexec@loki] HYD_uii_mpx_get_parameters (./ui/mpich/utils.c:1438): unable to parse user arguments
...
```

I believe that Anaconda's `mpi4py` is using mpich. If I use the system python it works.

```
$ /usr/bin/python spawn.py
mpi4py: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mpi4py/MPI.so
hello
```

The system `mpi4py` uses openmpi. Could there be some issue with `mpi4py` being built with conflicting MPI versions in Anaconda?

Also, the `mpi4py` package seems to function correctly in Anaconda when running under an `mpirun` call. For example

```
# test_mpi4py.py
import mpi4py.MPI as MPI
print MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
```

will give

```
$ mpirun -n 2 /home/wd15/anaconda/bin/python test_mpi4py.py
0
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and one solution was compiling mpi4py with openmpi instead of mpich (see 'Compute Pi' example in the mpi4py documentation).

See [this](https://trac.mpich.org/projects/mpich/ticket/1074) unresolved issue.

Tested on:
Ubuntu 16.04
Anaconda 4.0.0
python 3.5.0
mpich 3.2.0
openmpi 1.10.2
mpi4py 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda is bundled with MPICH.  Rather than using anaconda's mpi4py, you will need to build your own installation from source, explicitly linking against the system MPI installation.

Comment: I agree that I could build and install `mpi4py` in Anaconda's environment using the system openmpi, but it would be nice to understand why `spawn` isn't working with Anaconda's native MPI. Is there an inherent issue with using the `spawn` command with mpich?